# Spell specialization gust of wind

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer

My level 5 stormborn sorcerer is casting gust of wind affected by spell specialization.
Gust of wind is level 2 spell, but with spell specialization the level is increased by 2 to level 4. How does the increases spell levels affect the spell?

Does the strength of the wind increase by two steps to hurricane to correspond to the higher spell level?

Does the "blown away" size category increase from Tiny to Medium?

Does the duration increase from 1 round to 3?

Comment: The mythical version of this spell increases the wind speed one step. A second mythical step increases the duration by one round and adds 30 feet. Do these changes imply the wind speed can be increased as a higher spell level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spell specialization does not improve Gust of Wind in any form. Your only benefit from **increasing your caster level** is when your caster level is relevant. For gust of wind, none of the spell variables is affected by your caster level.

> Treat your **caster level** as being two higher for all level-variable effects of the spell.

The feat would help against creatures with spell resistance, since the check to overcome SR is 1d20+caster level. And on counterspell checks.

What you are confusing here is what is a *spell level* (0 being cantrips and orisons, and 9 being wish and miracle), and your *caster level*, being your level on the class that grants you the spell. In other words, **your caster level is your sorcerer level**.

When improved by spell specialization, your gust of wind is still a 2nd level spell, but the caster level is now 7. So if you must overcome spell resistance, you roll 1d20+7 instead of 1d20+5.